# How to recognise digits using Firebase ML Kit custom model

Tags: android, firebase, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

My android app have a need to read the text in a image and I am using the Firebase ML Kit for that purpose, it works well for the text which is in standard Roman script but it completely fails to read the digits in the below font family.

[image]

Especially for the digits 0, 1 & 6 Firebase result gives O, i, l, L & b, since it gives alternate letters for the same digit in different test I cannot apply regex to replace those letters with digits.

I have also tried the Firebase ML Kit cloud text recognition (Google Cloud Vision) for getting those digits as it is and it do have the same problem.

So my only option left is **Firebase ML Kit Custom Model** and I want to know on the possibility of reading text using **ML Kit Custom Model** which is based on **TensorFlowLite** model, I am asking this because all the android *ML Kit Custom Model* examples I saw is only used for detecting objects and didn't see any sample for reading text using MLKit custom model anywhere.

**Basically what I want is the same behaviour like Firebase offline/cloud text recognition but with a custom tensorflow lite model, is that possible?** Please describe

Comment: Why there is down vote for this question? I don't know whats wrong in the question, I have tried to write the question in the best possible way. Is it because of grammar or lack of research effort?

Comment: I think the downvote is for the lack of research effort. Digital Ocean made a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-neural-network-to-recognize-handwritten-digits-with-tensorflow) for what you're asking. And there are [more](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/training/handwritten_digit_cnn) and [more](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials) and [even more](https://kogence.com/app/docs/Digit_Recognition_Using_Tensorflow) resources available on the first result of a Google search

Comment: @ArthurAttout The OP clearly states that he tried "ML Kit cloud text recognition" and got bad results for certain digits. He is asking is there a more reliable solution. Legitimate question IMHO.

Comment: @ArthurAttout, the links you gave is useful but my question is based on FirebaseML custom model and its possibility on detecting digits using tflite model, I said that in my question too. I have modified the question for better understanding

Comment: @m.ka, have you found any solutions? we are having the same problem. were you able to add custom font family?

Comment: @ParthBhuva, currently there is no way to add custom font even though they are planning to implement it soon. What I am currently doing is replacing the letters with digits using regex and it works almost 70%

Comment: @m.ka,  thanks for the reply. can you please point me to the doc where you found about future implementation.

Comment: I think I got that info when I contacted firebase support team through mail, they said its in their future plan but didn't provide any ETA

Comment: Thanks for the info @m.ka, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible to recognize text with custom models via ML Kit. But there is a way how to do it with tensorflow.

[TensorFlow examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/optical_character_recognition/android)